# Naming a download attribute that's not from the same-origin

Tags: html

Regarding using the "download" attribute. I'm trying to give my image in the example below the name "myImage". This is not working I think for the reason stated here: [Download attribute with a file name not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working)

My question is, is there anyway around this?

The image is always going to be on a different server to my code.

```html
<a download="myImage.jpg" href="http://hekman.picarioxpo.com/7267-Jordan.pfs?width=250&p.tn=7000-022.tif,Aged-Gray.tif">Download image</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- Create a new canvas element

  - `document.createElement('canvas')`
- Create a new image element

  - `new Image()`
- Set the onload function to draw the image to the canvas

  - `image.onload`
  - `canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage()`
- Set the src you want

  - `image.src`
- Convert canvas to data uri

  - `canvas.toDataURL()`
- Put the result in the href of your anchor

(This works, because cross-origin policy doesn't apply to `<img>` src.)

Comment: Hi Szabolcs, thank you for your answer. I have managed to get this to work with one URL. I'm now trying to loop through an array of URL's. This might take more time to work out but at least I know that this is possible. Thank you for your time!