# Is it possible to force download using download attribute?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I know how to use `download` attribute to force download, but I want to do something different.

```
<a href="filename.mp4" download=""><img src="download.png"></a>
```

This is the `download` attribute which works properly, but I want to download using the `meta` tag like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=uploads/<?php echo $_POST["filename"]; ?>"> Please wait while your file start downloading.
```

It is working great with extensions like zipfile, rar, etc.. But when I try to use mp4, it opens up the file in a browser instead of force download.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download attribute with a file name not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working)

Comment: @SatishSaini no it is different dude! im using meta http-equiv refresh to download after 5 sec

Comment: yes it think it's different

Comment: @Jayanta is there anyway i can use ahref download attribute inside meta http-enquiv ?

Comment: just give me some moment sir

Comment: sir i found some solution @Noor Qureshi

Comment: @Jayanta Please share with us kindly!

Comment: first <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=some page link"> it is wait 5sec and redirect the page right, then use the javascript like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: in this line you find some solution

Comment: sir i found another solution

Comment: just wait for few moments sir

Comment: hi man i found the solution @Noor Qureshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change some thing. Sir i think it may help you:
The first page code:

```
<?php $file = $_POST["filename"]; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=hello.php?file=<?php echo $file; ?>">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Then i create a hello.php file and it contain:

```
<?php
$file = 'uploads/' . $_GET['file'];

if( !file_exists($file) ) die("File not found");

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
header('Content-type: vedio/mp4');

readfile($file);
?>
```

the process download the file automatic.

Comment: It didn't work for me. what if i wanna use that like this: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=uploads/<?php echo $file; ?>"> AND can you please tell me why you used $_POST for filename and then $_GET method?

Comment: it is work for me. you just need to use **Content-Disposition: attachment;** into another file header

Comment: i send the file name and in hello.php file to get the filename via $_GET

Comment: sir can you understand

Comment: you just need to make a new php file. and put the header settings

Comment: Basically i don't want to create another php file that way user can have a direct link example.com/hello.php?file=<?php echo $file; ?> i don't wanna give them a direct link.. i wanna make it like this example.com/<?php echo $file; ?> and using meta http-equiv they can't have direct link! they can only have it via console...

Comment: This is how im using it in begin.php https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8c1191d7da371b08695f1cb2ae782884

Comment: sir try again there is no redirection as you think. try again sir please.

Comment: sir you don't need to use 
**<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=uploads/<?php echo $file; ?>"> Please wait while your file start downloading. in the file (begin.php )**

Comment: this page only contain the header settings

Comment: you need 2 files one contain the meta data and other php file contain the header settings

Comment: if you don't understand please share your project sir. @NoorQureshi

Comment: this is my mail please send me a hi message here noorqureshics@gmail.com ill send you a project

Comment: are you get my mail? @NoorQureshi

Comment: i send the project. please tell me it is ok or not. @NoorQureshi

Comment: i am waiting for your ans sir.

Comment: one more think just put the **Dhoom.Dhaam.mp4** file into the **uploads** folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139419/discussion-between-jayanta-and-noor-qureshi).

Comment: There's still a problem with a downloading path: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) .... it is downloading from /download.php?file=media.mp4 ... it should be /uploads/media.mp4 right?

Comment: hi sir, i solve the issue. i send the file via mail. please response me.@NoorQureshi

Comment: Your code worked in my local computer! i don't know why it didn't work on my server! My server is windows 2016 i got this error: media.mp4 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: are you get the new mail sir

Comment: yes i got your mail! do you think im getting this problem because im using a sub directory example.com/d/uploads is that possible that's why im getting this? i try to change this $file = 'd/uploads/' . $_GET['file'];
and got file not found!

Comment: It worked @Jayanta i changed the memory limit for php to download larger files and it worked!

Comment: There's a limit issue now.. If the file is greater then 1024M it is not downloading them! I can use .htaccess showhow to force files > 1024M ? Because I have some files which are above 4GB