# Custom download name <a href> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the File name so i am trying to make use of Download Attribute.
Here is the Code.

```
<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/1200.png" download = "MyName">
  Click Me
</a>
```

The file name doesn't get change. It remains 1200.png.
I have noticed that when i use some local folder like '~/Images/file1.png' then it changes the name.

How to resolve this?

Comment: may be you can go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download attribute with a file name not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working)

Answer (score 4):

The [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) "only works for same-origin URLs".

You have observed that serving the file from the same origin ("some local folder") works, that is the only way to resolve it.