# Is there any way to set filename for HTML video tag when we use src as YouTube video root URL

Tags: html5-video, html5-history

```
<video controls disablePictureInPicture >
    <source src="https://r6---sn-uvu-2tme.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1609575422&ei=ntfvX_r4HcviogPYlqTYBw&ip=101.109.42.23&id=o-ALlNEoFZeOAiuFl8YkarSQ8DoUfqHGQGSdFxLI5KIjff&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=L5&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-uvu-2tme%2Csn-uvu-c336&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=6&pcm2cms=yes&pl=23&initcwndbps=1058750&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=0MPOtkwigfUSWUc9PykxRQgF&gir=yes&clen=4357379&ratebypass=yes&dur=68.382&lmt=1591493044603059&mt=1609553559&fvip=6&c=WEB&txp=5531432&n=s2-RHY1hBoqUa-TY&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhANbetE7ckou73sKIRLOdgepN7jrLmyBurwYqQ74kpAW1AiAsAtA9T3a6BgcQT3VcIXc_wtFjo85idgDXx7ks_yd72w%3D%3D&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgNhjUQLelWr9fwe0RaAY-EQIaNL-2vdKvztaPGlkohl0CIQC4spm2S00zPQ3x8gf7AUOb6JVMkUVKaU3ef041TxwD1Q%3D%3D" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

When I click on Download button its going to download the video with videoplayback.mp4 filename,
But I want myfileName.mp4 filename.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working), if you create the download button yourself, you can set it like this:

```
<a href="videoplayback.mp4" download="myfileName.mp4">Download</a>
```

But it only works if you have the video on the same domain as the page with the download link on it (As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33910145/869134)).

If the video is not on the same domain or you want a different name when right-clicking and choosing "Save as", you need to set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header on videoplayback.mp4 server side, like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfileName.mp4"
```

(I don't know your server software, so can't give a more specific example)

Comment: I want to download Youtube video with different filename. I have edited the question please read once