# How can I change the name of the file that will download?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link

```
<a href="/media/maca.pdf" download=""><img src="/static/images/download.svg" alt=""></a>
```

When I click download it starts downloading with the name maca.pdf. But I want to change that.

Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just simply need to have that name in the `download=""`. So if you wanted to name the file `myFile.pdf` then you would do

```
<a href="/media/maca.pdf" download="myFile"><img src="/static/images/download.svg" alt=""></a>
```

Now when you click download the file should be called `myFile.pdf`

So after looking around it seems it is because your file is coming from a different location. Check out this link [Download attribute with a file name not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working) and this one [Create a Downloadable Link using HTML5 Download Attribute](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/38-html-download-attribute/)

Comment: @maca oh? Does it still just try to download with the name `maca.pdf`?

Comment: yes! It is still trying to do tthat!

Comment: @maca what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome!

Comment: @maca take a peek at those links I just added